# Where does Shodan document fields that I can search by?

Tags: tls, shodan

where do I find information on all the fields that I can use shodan to search by? For example I can find a specific ssl vendor's certificates with ssl.cert.issuer.CN=asdf but what other fields can I search by?

Honestly Shodan's documentation is driving me nuts. It's so tutorial driven, and that's not what I need.

Comment: Hello! Unfortunately, requests for external resources are not on topic here. Perhaps you can describe what you want to do with Shodan instead?

Comment: I googled "shodan fields" and the top 4 hits were from Shodan, each with lists of fields. https://developer.shodan.io/api/banner-specification

Comment: The new website has a list of available filters: https://beta.shodan.io/search/filters

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thanks